# Use Ruby Bundler to build only non-development, non-test gems?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler, iron.io

I'm building an Iron.IO Ruby-only application and as part of their new docker workflow, I need to run bundler to build the bundled gems into ./bundle locally. However, it builds all the gems, including the group 'development' and group 'test' gems. It's wasted data so I'd like to be able to do a clean build of only the gems I actually need.

Is there a way to tell bundler to only build the non-dev, non-test gems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bundle install --without development test`

Comment: Yes it did! It's exactly what I needed. I just somehow missed that param in the docs.